# No, he was not wearing a wig

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, language

> It may be a bit of an overused trope, but my husband-to-be took me to eat in a nice restaurant for my birthday. When we entered the restaurant, I had a strange feeling that this was something I'd seen before... Then I remembered that I had applied for work in the restaurant a few years back, even sent them my CV and everything.
>
> The dinner was excellent – we had wonderful small appetizers, enjoyed some premium beef cuts, tasted some Rhone valley reds, and had coffee with milk afterwards. The only thing I have trouble remembering is what exactly we ordered for dessert.

Can you guess what we had for dessert?

Comment: Did you have ice cream?

Comment: Because who wouldn't order ice cream?

Comment: Did he have coffee pudding using **milk and coffee**

Comment: It was your birthday, you had cake ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For dessert, you might have had

> a gateau St. Honoré, or a marron glacé, or perhaps some delicious crème brûlée.

Let me tell the story again.

> (No, he was not wearing a *toupée*.) Despite the *cliché*, you and your *fiancé* went to a nice restaurant. You remembered sending them your *resumé*. You had some *canapés*, ate (perhaps) a *filet* cut of beef, drank (perhaps) some *Beaujolais* wine, and then enjoyed a *latte*.

[EDITED to add:] OP has explained in comments that in fact

> the actual intention was "words with diacritical marks" rather than specifically requiring e-acute *or* specifically requiring its sound to be at the end of the word. That resolves the single thing I was least happy about (the wine: Beaujolais is made *near* but not *in* the Rhone valley) as well as enabling better answers for the steak and the coffee.

Comment: She also had a rot13(qrwn-ih) and perhaps a (pnsr nh ynvg, orpnhfr ynggr vf Vgnyvna-vfu).

Comment: I wondered about the former (didn't think of the latter) but rejected it because the ending seems to be the thing rather than the presence somewhere of a particular glyph. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Just as a note, a latte is a glass of milk (in italy). A café au lait is a coffee with milk in france. My suspicion is that your third choice in your answer is the right one (particularly with the syllable count), but I had a moment of doubt and threw in another possible answer =)

Comment: I don't get the impression that these events are taking place in Italy. In anglophone countries, alas for authenticity, a "latte" is a coffee with milk in it. At some point I expect OP will weigh in and indicate whether it's the sound of the ending, or the presence of an e-acute, or some other thing, that's meant to be common. (I'd have liked it to be specifically an e-acute at the end every time, but couldn't make it work.)

Comment: I was actually thinking about rot13[jbeqf fcryyrq jvgu qvnpevgvpny znexf], but as it turns out a lot of the ones commonly used in English have the same ending. It probably would have been better to just use the ones that do. Instead I had [ragerpôgr, qéwà ih, pôgrf qh euôar] etc. That said, this answer works very well with the clues and the third guess here was actually my intended answer :)

Comment: I suspect they had hors d'oeuvres. Canapes would be very passe

Comment: I have a problem with the wine.  The wine mentioned in both current answers is NOT from the Rhône Valley.  In fact, the only AOC red wine I can find from the Rhône Valley that fits the answer is rot13[Pbgrf qh Ivinenvf], which I'd never heard of till today. Perhaps a different wine region should have been used?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @jafe. I've edited a summary into my answer.

Comment: Could the strange feeling of seeing something before be a déjà vu?

Comment: It certainly is, given that the original intention was "words with diacritical marks". But that didn't fit into my conjecture of "words ending in an e-acute sound", which is why I didn't mention it (though as it happens I did wonder about it).

Comment: @PhilMJones Part of why the wine actually seemed correct to me (in a perhaps overly smart/tricky way, which is how I usually get sidetracked with these things) is that while not technically part of the Rhone Valley, the region in question is at least partially within the département Rhone, soooo... Sometimes the more direct answer really *is* the right one, though :p

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, you missed "déja vu" in your retelling of the story

Answer (score 4):

Je pense que c'était...

> un [parfait](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parfait_(dessert)).

All credit to [@Gareth McCaughan's excellent answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/69411/51363) in spotting the pattern, this only really builds off of that (hopefully not too much steals off that), combined with it being, perhaps, fitting the "an overused trope" bit a little (although, granted, so does part of his answer, in the context), along with the mix of something that is also a common word in English... and because, forgiving the pun, it's the *perfect* finish. But at the same time, the word, while a borrowed word in English, has an actually different (still close, but not the same) meaning in English, which would easily explain the forgetting/confusion.

again, building off of what Gareth spotted, this would have been my rendition in that vein:

> No, he was not wearing a toupée. Despite the cliché, your fiancé took you to mangé in a [nice restaurant {this feels like I should have a word for this, but the only thing coming to mind is to simply use italian, rather than french, and then the pronounciation is falling rather than rising at the end... unless the twist is that it's a restaurant **à Nice**}] for your birthday (tanti auguri a te). Upon entré, you experienced some déjà vu, but had rappelé that you had previously appliqué for a position d'emploi, including sending them your Curriculum Vitae. You had lovely canapés, enjoyed chateaubriand filet, goûté des Beaujolais, and finally ordered some café au lait.

Comment: This is amazing :D Nice work.

Comment: hah, **blush** I totally got carried away, but thanks @jafe!